# HTML/CSS Gallery Website | Feedback on design and code

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal was to create a portfolio site for my motion design work. The website should be modern and intuitive, yet pose a good gallery. Please also comment on the dark mode functionality and responsiveness.

The full website is hosted under [timlwsk.bplaced.net](http://timlwsk.bplaced.net) (good domain coming soon). The contact form isn't working yet.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width,initial-scale=1″>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/43017aa80c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <title>timlwsk</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item header" id="header-l">
        <h1>timlwsk</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="item header" id="header-r">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><span title="Twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/timlwsk" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></span></li>
          <li><span title="Instagram"><a href="https://instagram.com/lwskdesign" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></span></li>
          <li><span title="Unsplash"><a href="https://unsplash.com/@lwskphotography" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></a></span></li>
          <li><span title="Reddit"><a href="https://reddit.com/u/timlwsk" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-reddit-alien"></i></a></span></li>
          <li><span title="Toggle Dark Mode"><a href="#" onclick="darkMode()"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></a></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/15.jpg" title="everybody gets high" alt="gallery image 15"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/14.jpg" title="spilt blood" alt="gallery image 14"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/13.jpg" title="drippin' gold" alt="gallery image 13"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/12.jpg" title="suffocated (white)" alt="gallery image 12"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/11.jpg" title="suffocated (black)" alt="gallery image 11"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/10.jpg" title="hannover" alt="gallery image 10"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/09.jpg" title="head in the clouds" alt="gallery image 09"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/08.jpg" title="arm" alt="gallery image 08"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/07.jpg" title="wilted" alt="gallery image 07"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/06.jpg" title="Honey, I am drowning" alt="gallery image 06"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/05.jpg" title="discobolus" alt="gallery image 05"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/04.jpg" title="AF1" alt="gallery image 04"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/03.jpg" title="sadness" alt="gallery image 03"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/02.jpg" title="happiness" alt="gallery image 02"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="./images/01.jpg" title="嗳 (Love)" alt="gallery image 01"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact" id="contact">
        <form class="contact-form" action="email.php" method="post">
          <label for="name">Your Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name">

          <label for="email">Your Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email">

          <label for="message">Your Messages</label>
          <textarea name="messahge"></textarea>

          <input type="submit"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>Copyright 2020</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/darkmode.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**master.css**

```css
/*   grid-area: <name> | <row-start> / <column-start> / <row-end> / <column-end>; */

:root, [data-theme="light"] {
  --bg-color: #ffffff;
  --bg-color-inv: #000000;
  --outline-color: #000000;
  --text-primary: #000000;
  --text-primary-inv: #ffffff;
  --text-secondary: #a4a4a4;
  --text-secondary-hover: #000000;
  --chivo: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --bg-color: #121212;
  --bg-color-inv: #dadada;
  --outline-color: #dadada;
  --text-primary: #dadada;
  --text-primary-inv: #000000;
  --text-secondary: #919191;
  --text-secondary-hover: #dadada;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  font-size: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Transitions */
html, #header-r ul li a:link, #header-r ul li a:visited, #header-r ul li a:hover, input[type=submit], input[type=submit]:hover, html {
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% auto 10%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#header-l {
  grid-area: 1/2/1/2;
  justify-self: left;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#header-r {
  grid-area: 1/2/1/2;
  justify-self: right;
  align-self: center;
}

#header-r ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

#header-r ul li a:link, #header-r ul li a:visited {
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header-r ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--text-secondary-hover);
}

.gallery {
  font-size: 0;
  grid-column: 2/2;
}

.img-wrapper {
  width: calc(100%/1);
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.contact {
  grid-area: 3/2/3/2;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  width: calc(2/3);
  margin-top: 10%;
}

label {
  font-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text],  textarea{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=submit], select, textarea {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: var(--chivo);
  border: 1px solid var(--outline-color);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: var(--text-primary);
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: var(--bg-color-inv);
  color: var(--text-primary-inv);
}

textarea {
  height: 20vh;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: 4/2/4/2;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

@media (min-width: 1080px) /* Large Devices */ {
  html {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .img-wrapper {
    width: calc(100%/3);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 2560px) /* Large Devices */ {
  html {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
  }

  .img-wrapper {
    width: calc(100%/5);
  }
}
```

**darkmode.js**

```js
var isOn = false;
function darkMode () {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', ['dark', 'light'][+isOn]);
    isOn = !isOn;
}
```

Comment: Is the code posted in the question working? If so remove the comment about the contact form which makes the question off-topic.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are first starting out with a new website, then a content management system such as WordPress or Drupal is a better way to go. There will be a lot less code required to implement it.

Comment: @BCdotWEB done, I edited the title!

Comment: @pacmaninbw Sorry, but I am not quite sure why the question becomes off-topic, when I state that a part of the website isn't coded yet. Furthermore, I love to code but thanks for the tip!

Comment: To explain why a comment about the code not working would make the question off-topic please see our help center on how to ask a good question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help. Content management systems simply reduce the amount of code necessary, they don't remove the need for code unless the site doesn't do anything. I can code in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but if I was starting a new website I would use a content management system to reduce the amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: good job! I like the simple layout and only-one-breakpoint-design. But like always there are some little things I would change.

## 1 [HTML5 Semantic Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Tell your browser what is a header, section, footer and so on.

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center-vertically justify-space-between">
      <div>Logo</div>
      <div>Stuff</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section id="gallery" class="panel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid grid-3-3-3">
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><img src="" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <form action=""></form>
  </div>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</footer>
```

## 2 Grid

I think it isn't necessary to make your whole container a CSS grid. I think it makes it harder to build on top of it/less scalable. For example if, at some point, you would like to add a full width section you would need to work with negative margins. Of course this is possible, but I think it is kind of "hacky". I would suggest to use a container class in every section. That way there would be no problem to add a full width section without the container class in the future. These programmers... always trying to predict the future...

Also, if you like to expand your knowledge, you could have a look at Sass. It helps you to keep your CSS modular. Here is an example how I use Sass. I know you didn't ask for that, but I hope it is interesting for you nonetheless
.

**variables.sass**

```
// TYPOGRAPHY
$primaryFont: 'Public Sans', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif
$secondaryFont: 'Public Sans', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif
$baseTextSize: 1.6rem
$textColor: #222

// MARGINS
$margin: 2rem
$margin-2: 4rem

// BREAKPOINTS
$mobileS: "max-width: 374px"
$mobileM: "min-width: 375px"
$tablet: "min-width: 768px"
```

**layout.sass**

```
.container
    margin: 0 auto

@media($mobileS)
    .container
        width: 100%

@media($tablet)
    .container
        width: 700px
```

**helper-classes.sass**

```
.justify-space-between
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between

.center-vertically
    display: flex
    align-items: center
```

Comment: Hi Dennis! Thank you for your feedback, I really appreciate it! I actually tried to have a look at Sass but was quickly turned down by the lack of good-looking apps for windows. Do you got any recommendations (using atom atm)?

Comment: I'm not on Windows, so I don't really know what is popular there. But maybe this might help you: https://atom.io/packages/sass-autocompile